# How to download mpdf from angularjs $http post and codeiginter?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, mpdf

When clicking on download PDF, I am calling a $http post to CI controller and writing a mPdf function to download.

```
<button class="btn btn-green add-btn btn-w147" ng-model="exportPDF" ng-click="exportPdf()">Export To PDF</button>
```

In JS file, I am performing the following action:

```
$http({
            url: 'audit-pdf-export',
            method: 'POST',
            data: serializeData({
              'session_id': session_id,
              'advertiser_id': advertiser_id,
              'startDate' : startDate,
              'endDate' : endDate,

            }),
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
      })
      .success(function(response){
          $rootScope.opendloader = false;

        console.log(response);
      });
```

And in codeiginter i am downloading the PDF

```
 public function pdf_export()  {
  $data = $this->input->post();
  $result = $this->advertiser_mod->fetch_advertiser_logs($data);
  $res['result'] = $result;
  $html = $this->load->view('templates/audit_log_pdfView', $res,true);
  $filename = "Aduit trail";
  $this->load->library('mpdf');
  $mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  $mpdf->Output($filename . ".pdf", 'D'); }
```

And the file output is

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1046>>
stream
x­VÍn$5îs?EiOpc]þ9 eGâ8õd«ÉBy&Þ*Ûåîil(J÷|5®òWÿwàµöìy3Ûú¡=©Ál!grá¯¯á=¼á,<ö3úÝmÇÉñOCû¿Õ9íl~0¿HM«±g£!;Ø
```

I need to download the pdf file.

Comment: save the file on your server - send the filepath and filename back to js - create a hidden link and trigger it with click

Comment: Cant i directly download the file without saving the file in the server @sintakonte